# asp.net core default ErrorMessageResourceName and Type

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have this class:

```
public class CategoryViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "RequiredErrorMessage", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources)), StringLength(100, ErrorMessageResourceName = "IdStringLengthErrorMessage", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources))] public string Id { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "RequiredErrorMessage", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources)), StringLength(255, ErrorMessageResourceName = "StringLengthErrorMessage", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources))] public string Name { get; set; }
    [StringLength(255, ErrorMessageResourceName = "StringLengthErrorMessage", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources))] public string Image { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see it has custom error messages coming from my **Resources.resx** file.
I am about to create a lot more models and I would like it if I didn't have to specify the `ErrorMessageResourceName` and `ErrorMessageResourceType` for each one.

I would like to set all **Required** attributes to use my **RequiredErrorMessage** and my **StringLength** attributes to use **StringLengthErrorMessage**.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

As described in ASP.NET Core documentations, [Data annotation localization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-2.1#dataannotations-localization) can be configured in the startup file, then you could provide error messages inside the attribute tags.

1.Configure data annotation localization to use a shared resource file , a dummy class named SharedResources is used for shared resources:

```
services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2)
                .AddViewLocalization(o => o.ResourcesPath = "Resources")
                .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization(o =>
                 {
                     var type = typeof(SharedResources);
                     var assemblyName = new AssemblyName(type.GetTypeInfo().Assembly.FullName);
                     var factory = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<IStringLocalizerFactory>();
                     var localizer = factory.Create("SharedResources", assemblyName.Name);
                     o.DataAnnotationLocalizerProvider = (t, f) => localizer;

                 });
```

2. You could add resource files like below :

[image]

[image]

3.Modify  model by decorating all its properties with relevant attributes

```
public class EmuItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string SearchName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter value for {0}")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

The screenshot of the result :
[image]

Reference :http://www.ziyad.info/en/articles/16-Localizing_DataAnnotations

Comment: thanks for this, it is useful, but it isn't what I meant. You see on your required attribute, you put "Please enter a value for {0}". I want to set that message as a default for all required attributes